# Handling Internet Connection: Special Case

Tags: android, internet-connection

Lets say there is two mobile A and B. Turn on the hotspot of Mobile A, and connect the Mobile B.
Now turn off the Mobile Data of Mobile A. 
For Mobile B, there is a network available but it won't be able to connect because the Mobile Data is off in Mobile A.

**How to handle this in coding?**

I'm checking Internet Connection like this.

```
  public boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    boolean connected = false;

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    connected = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() &&
            networkInfo.isConnected();
    return connected;
}
```

From Activity, I'm doing like this.

```
 if (isNetworkConnected()) {
        // Connection Available
 } else {
        // No Connection
 }
```

It should come in else part, but it's not coming.

Comment: Handle what in coding?

Comment: you can make a ping on Internet from background thread if response is success means you are connected otherwise not

Comment: As Rutvik said, you have a network connection (to Mobile A) just not internet, you will have to try getting something like a ping from the internet and checking on a failure.

Comment: I'll try that, and will update here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check using InetAddress also

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
    try {
        InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com"); 
        //You can replace it with your name
            return !ipAddr.equals("");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure below are requested in manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Answer (score 1):

You may have to do an `openConnection()` to a URI. Try using the following code in a runnable:

```
        public boolean isHostReachable() {
          connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
          if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {    
           try{     
            URI uri = new URI(YOUR_URL_HERE);
            String domainName = uri.getScheme() + "://" + uri.getRawAuthority();
            URL url = new URL(domainName);
            URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
            urlConn.connect();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: YOUR_URL_HERE -> use your base API url. By that way you will come to know if your API is up and working or down.

Answer (score 0):

Add ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

To detect actual internet connection, you need to test using Ping for example, this code will ping www.google.com to check for connection, it ties to use the ping command (because of its reliability), if not available on an error occurred, it fallbacks to InetAddress isReachable method.

```
public boolean isConnected(){
 try{
    Process p1 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 www.google.com");
    int returnVal = p1.waitFor();
    return returnVal==0;
   } catch(Exception e){
     //fallback to java's ICMP implementation
     return InetAddress.getByName("8.8.8.8").isReachable(1000);
   }
}
```